# Как принимать POST/GET запросы?

Tags: python, http, https

Python. Не предлагайте большие фреймворки по типу Django/Flask и т.д. Максимально оптимизированный код. Мне нужен небольшой код, принимающий запросы. Чтобы можно было отдельно получить IP и данные POST запроса.

Comment: Это `Flask` то "большой фреймворк"? Вы издеваетесь? )

Comment: мне просто нужен максимально оптимизированный метод получения запросов

Comment: Оптимизированный под что? Оптимизация - это улучшение какого-либо параметра. Например, количество используемой памяти. Или скорость обработки одного запроса. Или простота написания кода. Или количество обрабатываемых запросов в секунду. Вы что оптимизировать то хотите? Если простоту кода, то проще чем `Flask` уже почти некуда.

Comment: Попробуйте `FastAPI`, раз уж Вам `Flask` не угодил. Можно на `aiohttp` поупражняться.